# How to implement Google Earth in Android Studio? I want a map view like Globe

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-earth

I have searched the internet but could not find solution about this.
I need a Globe map like google earth and want o perform action on earth..

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps Android SDK currently doesn't have this feature. There is a corresponding feature request in Google issue tracker. You can see it at

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63903968

Feel free to star the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications from Google.

Hopefully one day Google implements it.